# When a Value in a particular Range = to value in another range in the same sheet, then

Tags: vba

Supposedly in B Column I have a List of client names and of one the client eg. ABC has a rule of not accepting "AR" as Benefits. when the user has to update the Benefits for clients from the drop down list via validations a pop up msg 'STOP' should come once the user selects 'AR' Benefits for ABC client

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried so far, so we can help you where you are stuck. Also, have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't have anything so far. as I don't know anything about VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I don't have anything so far. as I don't know anything about VBA. Inn Column B there are list of client - Zurich, POSH, BOSCH, ACE, COMPASS. and in Column C captioned as Benefits the User has to update the Benefits against these clients. But one of the client i.e. COMPASS has a rule of not using AR as a benefit. So basically I want a msg pop up 'STOP' as the user selects AR for this particular client from a drop down. The drop down is listed as BE,NB, AR, SE, ID

Comment: You can do that via `data validation`, where you can allow the input to be from a certain list and show an error message when something else is applied. See the [Microsoft guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29FECBCC-D1B9-42C1-9D76-EFF3CE5F7249) for an example

Comment: I've tried data validation before didn't work. Hence, thought it  may work via vba